# Using Rank function in Join

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, ranking

I am using the below oracle code to find the top 5 stores that have the most items sold.  Anything after those 5 stores should be grouped together into an "Other" bucket rank 6.  Run_id and scenario_ID have a one to one relationship.  This code works when there is only one run_id and one scenario_id.  This code works great when I only have one run_id and one scenario_id.  However, for efficency I would like to pull up the top 5 rank for each scenario with only when query.  When I do that then the first run_id will show me the top 5 chains and the all other bucket, and every run_id after that only shows the all other bucket with a rank of 6.

```
SELECT c.SCENARIO_ID, case when C.YEAR_MONTH_NBR >= to_char(r.proj_start_dt,'YYYYMM') then 'G' else 'L' End as overUnd, case when rnk <= 5 then c.model_nme else 'Other' end as Chain_Nme, sum(c.item_qty), case when rnk <= 5 then rnk else 6 end as final_rank
  from USR.pdr_summary c
  Left Outer Join run_tbl r on c.run_id = r.run_id
  Left join (SELECT c.scenario_id, c.model_nme, rank () over (order by c.scenario_id, sum(C.item_qty) desc) as Rnk
     from USR.pdr_summary c
     where c.run_id IN ('1110','1111','1112','1113')
         and c.scenario_id IN('5423','5424','5425','5426')
         and c.model_nme <> 'Other Retail'
     group by c.scenario_id, c.model_nme) rank_data
     on rank_data.model_nme = c.model_nme
      and rank_data.scenario_id = c.scenario_id
     where c.run_id IN ('1110','1111','1112','1113')
         and c.scenario_id IN('5423','5424','5425','5426')
  group by c.SCENARIO_ID, case when C.YEAR_MONTH_NBR >= to_char(r.proj_start_dt,'YYYYMM') then 'G' else 'L' End, case when rnk <= 5 then c.model_nme else 'Other' end, case when rnk <= 5 then rnk else 6 end
     order by c.SCENARIO_ID, overUnd, case when rnk <= 5 then rnk else 6 end asc
```

When I remove the `and rank_data.scenario_id = c.scenario_id` line from the rank data query then for some scenarios I get all 6 ranks and others I would get rank 1, 3, 5, and 6 or 1,2,4, and 6.

I think this is an issue with the way I am doing the joins, but I can't figure out why?

My Desired results are below:

```
Scenario_id OverUnd Chain_nme   item_qty    rank
5423    G   Walmart        1000     1
5423    G   Amazon          950     2
5423    G   Target      750     3
5423    G   Walgreens   600     4
5423    G   CVS     500     5
5423    G   Other       800     6
5423    L   Trader Joe  1000        1
5423    L   Amazon          950     2
5423    L   Target      750     3
5423    L   Walgreens   600     4
5423    L   Walmart         500     5
5423    L   Other       800     6
5424    G   Walgreens   1000        1
5424    G   Amazon          950     2
5424    G   Target      750     3
5424    G   Walmart         600     4
5424    G   CVS     500     5
5424    G   Other       800     6
5424    L   Trader Joe  1000        1
5424    L   Amazon          950     2
5424    L   Target      750     3
5424    L   Walgreens   600     4
5424    L   Walmart         500     5
5424    L   Other       800     6
```

What I am getting is:

```
Scenario_id OverUnd Chain_nme   item_qty    rank
5423        G       Walmart 1000        1
5423        G       Amazon  950     2
5423        G       Target      750     3
5423        G       Walgreens   600     4
5423        G       CVS     500     5
5423        G       Other       800     6
5423        L       Trader Joe  1000        1
5423        L       Amazon  950     2
5423        L       Target      750     3
5423        L       Walgreens   600     4
5423        L       Walmart 500     5
5423        L       Other       800     6
5424        G       Other       700     6
5424        L       Other       900     6
5425        G       Other       700     6
5425        L       Other       900     6
5426        G       Other       700     6
5426        L       Other       900     6
```

Sorry I am not sure how to make it look like a table when I copy/paste the data in.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added my results and what I would like it to look like.

Answer (score 0):

Someone emailed me the answer to my question. I needed to rank by scenario_id as well as item_qty.

```
(partition by c.scenario_id order by c.scenario_id, sum(C.item_qty) desc) as Rnk
```